# Check if a text contains at least one string from a list of strings - Dart - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings

```
 var list = ['my name is', 'people call me', 'i am', 'you can call me'];
```

I'd like to check if a text contains at least one expression from my list of strings before executing an if statement

```
      if (text.toLowerCase().contains("my name is") ||
          text.toLowerCase().contains("people call me") || text.toLowerCase().contains("i am")) {
       
//do something

      }
```

Right now this is what I'm doing but it won't work in the long run as my list will get longer

I need to return true if `text.contains(anyStringfromMyList)`

---

*Edit :
Also I'd like to know (return) which item from this list was found in the `text`*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could use [any](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/Iterable/any.html) method of the list

```
  var list = ['my name is', 'people call me', 'i am', 'you can call me'];
  String text = "my name is Adam";

  if (list.any((item) => text.toLowerCase().contains(item))) {
    //do something
  }
```

or with regex

```
  var regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:${list.join('|')})\\b", caseSensitive: false);
  if (regex.hasMatch(text)) {
    //do something
  }
```

for getting value of found item:

```
  String foundText = list.firstWhere((item) => text.toLowerCase().contains(item), orElse: () => "");
  if (foundText != "") {
    print(foundText);
  }
```

for getting values of all found items:

```
  List<String> foundItems = list.where((item) => text.toLowerCase().contains(item)).toList();
  if (foundItems.isNotEmpty) {
    print(foundItems);
  }
```

Comment: thank you ! - I chose the first approach as I don't understand regex  - one more question should I declare my list as `final` or `static const` if it doesn't change ?

Comment: also could you add how to `return` which item from the list was found contained in the text ? : )

Comment: I would go with const

Comment: I wish I could upvote 10 times your answer ! thank you so much ⚡️